# Firefox: Handle media abort exception in HTML5 video element with js (NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_ABORT_ERR)

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-video, mediaelement, domexception

Given a video element with a large video and a user with slow connection in Firefox, skipping around the video after playing but before completely being loaded leads to

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The fetching process for the media resource was aborted by the user agent at the user's request.

**Presets:**

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0

```
<video controls>
  <source src="http://help.de/somelargevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

- throttle network activity to minimum
- skip video progress somewhere
- hit play in the controls
- skip to some former point before the loading has finished

**Result**
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The fetching process for the media resource was aborted by the user agent at the user's request.

**Question**
Any ideas to gracefully catch this?
Custom control implementations for catching the rejection errors are not an option.

And actually after reading the docs I would have expected Firefox to internally handle this similar to Chrome or maybe just fire an abort event [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/abort_event](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), as it is as deliberate abort action as the message says.